# can not connect to mysql by external network ip

Tags: mysql

I'm using CentOS 6.5 64bit AND mysql-server-5.5.43-29.el6.art.x86_64
External network IP address is 118.192.87.188

first:

```
vim /etc/sysconfig/iptables
-A INPUT -m state --state NEW -m tcp -p tcp --dport 3306 -j ACCEPT
:wq
```

second:

```
yum -y install mysql mysql-server
/etc/init.d/mysqld start
chkconfig mysqld on
cp /usr/share/mysql/my-medium.cnf /etc/my.cnf
```

third:

```
mysql_secure_installation
    .......
"Thanks for using MySQL!"
```

forth:

```
/etc/init.d/mysqld restart
```

fifth:

```
mysql -uroot -ppasswd -P3306
mysql>use mysql;
mysql>select user,host from user;
mysql>update user set host='%' where user='root';
mysql>GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'passwd' WITH GRANT OPTION;
mysql>flush privileges;
```

question:
I can connect to mysql in this CentOS by using:

```
mysql -uroot -ppasswd -P3306
mysql -uroot -ppasswd -hlocalhost -P3306
mysql -uroot -ppasswd -h127.0.0.1 -P3306
mysql -uroot -ppasswd -h118.192.87.188 -P3306
```

But in my Ubuntu:

```
mysql -uroot -ppasswd -h118.192.87.188 -P3306
```

30 seconds later:

> ERROR 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on '118.192.87.188' (110)

Comment: Does the MySQL server instance allow remote connections to be opened?

Comment: https://rtcamp.com/tutorials/mysql/remote-access/

Comment: on /etc/mysql/my.cnf you should set bind=0.0.0.0 or comment it out that .